# Aggregate data inside case statement

Tags: mysql, case, aggregate

I want to create 4 groups based on *submit_volume* and then calculate percentage of each group over total number of *submit_volume*

So far I used this query

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN submit_volume <= 60 then '60 Request'
           WHEN submit_volume > 60
                AND submit_volume <= 150 then '60-150 Request'
           WHEN submit_volume > 150
                AND submit_volume <= 1000 then '150-1K Request'
           WHEN submit_volume > 1000 then 'Over 1K Request'
       END,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN submit_volume <= 60 then submit_volume
               WHEN submit_volume > 60
                    AND submit_volume <= 150 then submit_volume
               WHEN submit_volume > 150
                    AND submit_volume <= 1000 then submit_volume
               WHEN submit_volume > 1000 then submit_volume
           END)
FROM mydatabase.submit_volume
GROUP BY 1
```

And got this table

```
| group| sum| 
| 60-150 Request   | 87247    |
| 60 Request       | 105934   |
| Over 1K Request  | 2385947  |
| 150-1K Request   | 777186   |
```

So can I have the percentage of each group without using subquery? I tried this but I got the same 100% for all groups

```
sum(CASE
   WHEN submit_volume <= 60 then submit_volume
   WHEN submit_volume > 60
      AND submit_volume <= 150 then submit_volume
   WHEN submit_volume > 150
      AND submit_volume <= 1000 then submit_volume
   WHEN submit_volume > 1000 then submit_volume
END) / sum(submit_volume) * 100.0 as percentage
```

Comment: Of course... why you have no tested this simply? Another point is that your CASE is strange - you return `submit_volume` for ANY of conditions... you must divide each separate sum by total sum.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CASE` expression that you use to group can be simplified and the `SUM()` needs only `submit_volume`.
Cross join to the table a query that returns the total `submit_volume` of the table and use it to get the percentage:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN sv.submit_volume <= 60 then '60 Request'
           WHEN sv.submit_volume <= 150 then '60-150 Request'
           WHEN sv.submit_volume <= 1000 then '150-1K Request'
           WHEN sv.submit_volume > 1000 then 'Over 1K Request' -- or ELSE 'Over 1K Request'
       END request,
       SUM(sv.submit_volume) / MAX(t.total) * 100.0 percentage 
FROM mydatabase.submit_volume sv 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(submit_volume) total FROM mydatabase.submit_volume) t
GROUP BY request
```

For MySql 8.0+ it's easier with `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN submit_volume <= 60 then '60 Request'
           WHEN submit_volume <= 150 then '60-150 Request'
           WHEN submit_volume <= 1000 then '150-1K Request'
           WHEN submit_volume > 1000 then 'Over 1K Request' -- or ELSE 'Over 1K Request'
       END request,
       SUM(submit_volume) / SUM(SUM(submit_volume)) OVER () * 100.0 percentage 
FROM submit_volume 
GROUP BY request
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afa64f650970400e11a8db1e059d5161).

Comment: Thanks for your window function query!